# Problem with scaffolding identity in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to scaffold identity on UI `SuplementShop.WEB.Mvc` solution in Visual Studio 2022.

I'm new to ASP.NET so I hope somebody can help me :)

Open repository on GitHub:
(version before scaffolding)

https://github.com/7LinesOfCode/SuplementShopWEB.MVC

Thanks in advance for every response :)

I want to make Login and Register scaffold, with data context
"Context (`Suplement.WEB.Mvc.Infrastructure`)". After that step my app can't compile anymore.

Observations: after making scaffolding (as I said above) output in the console look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3YSO.png)

After scaffolding if I try to debug my app, I get an exception in

```
var app = builder.Build()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM3N5.png)

List of errors:

```
 System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
```

SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Interfaces.IOrderService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Services.OrderService': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.OrderRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Interfaces.ICustomerService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Services.CustomerService': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.CustomerRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Interfaces.IItemService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Application.Services.ItemService': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.ItemRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Domain.Interface.IOrderRepository Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.OrderRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.OrderRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Domain.Interface.ICustomerRepository Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.CustomerRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.CustomerRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Domain.Interface.IItemRepository Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.ItemRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Context' while attempting to activate 'SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure.Repositories.ItemRepository'.)'

After that I can find a new connection string in `appsettings.json`.

Before scaffolding action, application had no errors and was working fine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

After I cloned your project from github, I find the error and fix them, You can follow these steps.

First change your `dbcontext` class name, give it an unique name like `MyApplicationDbcontext` instead of just called `Context`, Then add related page in Scuffolding identity according to this `dbcontext`

[image]

Then click add button to add these identity pages.

Now you need to add-migration and update-database, First set your MVC project as the startup project, Then in Package Manager Console, set Infrastructure project as default project.

[image]

Finally use

```
add-migration MyMigration -Context MyApplicationDbcontext

update-database -Context MyApplicationDbcontext
```

to migration and create database.

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Thank u. I follow your steps like u said, but its doesn't work in my case. I found i have this table in database "dbo.AspNetUsers", before even take any action like  scaffolding.

Comment: think it's something with DB or migrations

Comment: Hi @KarolChmieliński after i cloned your project, i find there are some migration files in  your project, So If there is nothing important in your database, you can try to delete this database and add-migration/update-database again.

Comment: I will try drop-database there were just temporary data

Comment: @KarolChmieliński waiting for your result

Comment: I doesn't work still,  have u also after scaffolding this comunicate in output "no database provider..."? That's look like something wrong with database

Comment: I don't get this error message, Which step cause it? after you click add button to generate identity page or after add-migration/update-database ?

Comment: After generate identity page, even this communicate i have new (looks like defult mssql) connection string in appsettings.json

Comment: In Add Identity Page, Have you selected the correct DbContext class?

Comment: I hope so because i have only one possible in drop down list menu, like in your screen above. May i should add it manually not from list?

Comment: you need to make sure the dbcontext you selected is the MyApplicationDbcontext in Infrastructure project

Comment: Im sure, its "MyAppContext (SuplementShopWEB.MVC.Infrastructure)". But is not that wird i have this table "dbo.AspNetUsers" already in database?

Comment: Sorry , i can't reproduce this error in my local machine, Your project works correctly in my  visual studio.

Comment: Could u tell me what sql database u use? is that sql serwer express?

Comment: I just use local sql server.

Comment: Check the update in my answer, i get connect string from `Properties`

Comment: I resolve my problem, with my friend support. All what i needed to do was delete connection string whoes was generated by scaffodling in Visual Studio, delete new context class in area => data catalog, and last but no least change my Context class name from "Context.cs" to something other. And that's how i fixed a bug :)  @XinranShen